# After Deploy SSRS reports into Development Server How will configure to dotnet applcation?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I deployed SSRS reports into deployment server.

Actually, I would like to Access  those reports into Dotnet application,

Can anyone tell me the details steps How can i achieve this?

Am totally new to SSRS,give me your suggessions?

Comment: Hi ,I will use Asp.net as the client application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should design your report in BIDS, then deploy the report on the report server, you might have already done this from your information. What you should do is To add the Report Viewer control to the Web page:

1. Drag and drop the Report Viewer icon onto the WebForm design surface. The SmartTags panel for the control is automatically displayed.
2. In the ReportViewer Tasks smart tags panel, in Choose Report, select Server Report.
3. In the Report Server text box, type the report server URL. The default URL syntax is `http://yourReportServer/reportserver`. The actual URL that is used in your installation might be different depending on how the report server virtual directory settings are configured.
4. In the Report Path text box, type the fully qualified path of a published report. When referencing a report on a report server in native mode, the report path starts with a forward slash ( / ); For example: /Adventureworks 2008 Sample Reports/Company Sales 2008

Brouswer the report via IE, you will see the report deployed on the report server.

**Reference:**

Configuring ReportViewer for Remote Processing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075.aspx

Using the ReportViewer Tasks Smart Tags Panel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252072(VS.80).aspx